# Product of independent random variables property

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need to prove that the joint distribution function of a vector random variable is equal to the product of distribution functions if and only if the random variables are independent

$$\xi_1, \xi_2  \text{- discrete random variables. } \vec{\xi} = (\xi_1, \xi_2). \text{ Prove that } F_\vec{\xi}(a_1,a_2) = F_{\xi_1}(a_1)F_{\xi_2}(a_2),\ a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{R}\iff\ \xi_1, \xi_2 \text{ - independent.}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows immediately from the definition of independence.  $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent if $P(X1\in S_1 \cap X_2\in S_2)=P(X1\in S_1)\times P( X_2\in S_2)$ where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are arbitrary.

For your case $F_{X_k}(a_k)=P(X_k\le a_k)$ is given where $S_k$ consists of all possibilities $\le a_k$.

For the other direction, use let $S_k$ be a particular vale of $X_k$ and $T_k$ the next lower value of $X_k$. Then $P(S_1\cap S_2)=F(S_1,S_2)-F(S_1,T_2)-F(T_1,S_2)+F(T_1,T_2)$

where $F$ is the joint distribution.  Using $F(a_1,a_2)=F_{X_1}(a_1)\times F_{X_2}(a_2)$, we get $P(S_1\cap S_2)=P(S_1)\times P(S_2)$.

Comment: Okay, one way proven. And how to prove the other way (from right to left)?

Comment: Answer supplement for your question.